# How can I enable themes in Gnome Shell?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I have installed the GNOME Shell Theming extension and enabled it in the `gnome-tweak-tool`.

I have installed some themes in my `~/.themes` folder but still I cannot select any shell themes.

How can I enable and select GNOME Shell themes?

Comment: Interesting, my original question contained the word broken, now it hass been edited, 8 minutes after i asked it

Comment: It looks like it's been edited to remove the mistakes.  By the way, do you think you'll ever follow the rules of this site and accept some of the answers to your previous questions?   You'll probably get more help if you do.

Comment: Which themes have you been trying?  please edit your question with links to the themes.

Comment: If you want to install the themes system-wide instead of just your user account, you can put the themes in /usr/share/themes/

Answer (score 5):

To select a theme, go to the *Theme* tab in Gnome tweak tool. Next to shell theme, you should see a button the says "None" with a folder icon. If you see a triangle with an exclamation point, it means that you have not installed the gnome-shell theme selector extension, which can be installed using the following commands in a terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

Once the extension is installed, select the the .zip file for the theme that you want to install (Do NOT unpack it) by clicking on the "None" button in the Theme tab of gnome-tweak-tool. Then, select it from the list to the right of the "None" button.

Comment: For me, the important thing was to know I must leave the .zip file in ~/.themes/ *unpacked*. In a number of cases, instructions accompanying gnome-shell themes I've found "in the wild" seem to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest gnome shell 3.0+, you can just go to the extensions tab in the gnome tweak tool and switch the "User themes" one on. This extension is included by default in all the gnome shell but is initially disabled by default.

Now just go to the shell themes option and add the required theme.

I hope it helps!